# understanding the tcp header

Tags: tcpdump

The first 16 bits in a tcp header, (rfc793), are for the source port, right? The next 16 are for the destination port. When I run `tcpdump -xx` I can recognise MAC addresses of boxes on my system. Does this mean that the "ports" are MAC addresses?

Comment: What is the switch `-xx` doing?, I only see `-x` and `-X` in the man page for tcpdump. The only switches I see that support multiple copies are `v`, `t`, `n`, and `d`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Which version of `tcpdump` are you using? 4.3.0 has `-xx`.

Comment: @grawity I don't have my box near me right now so I just googled it and got [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tcpdump.htm)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That one is from 2002. The latest version is on the [official website](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html).

Answer (score 3):

No, they aren't.

Regardless of its name, tcpdump captures packets at the lowest possible level – it doesn't limit itself to just TCP.

When you use `-xx`, tcpdump outputs the *link layer* header of all packets, so the first 4 bytes of the output aren't TCP – they are part of the Ethernet frame.

Even with plain `-x`, tcpdump would print the IP header before TCP/UDP.

If you want to see the packet structure, use Wireshark instead – it will display every packet as a tree, and highlight the specific bytes for every value.

Comment: Great! So it looks like I was using the wrong options and was getting the link layer include.